# Quando é que se começou a usar «ch», «lh» e «nh» como em «chato», «filho» e «vinho»?

Tags: ortografia, origem-histórica

Creio que o ***ch*** deve ser anterior ao tempo dos afonsinhos, pois existe também noutras línguas para representar o mesmo som ou um som parecido. Mas o ***lh*** e o ***nh*** parecem só existir no português. O som que nós representamos por ***nh*** é representado por ***gn*** no francês e italiano, e por ***ñ*** no espanhol:

> Espanhol, [español](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GUSX1EQ), [espagnol](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/espagnol/31021?q=espagnol#30940), [spagnolo](http://www.dizionario-italiano.it/dizionario-italiano.php?parola=spagnolo)

E o que nós representamos por ***lh***, é representado por ***ll*** no espanhol, e por ***gli*** no italiano:

> Maravilha, [maravilla](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OMF3oTt), [maraviglia](http://www.dizionario-italiano.it/dizionario-italiano.php?parola=maraviglia).

O ***lh*** e o ***nh*** devem portanto ter sido invenções nossas, a menos que os outros as tenham também usado e depois abandonado, o que me parece menos provável. Quando apareceram então o ***lh*** e o ***nh***?

Comment: Vieram do provençal. A gente quis ser diferente dos castelhanos.

Comment: @Artefacto E foi quando, isso? Nós antes usávamos ***ll*** e ***ñ***?

Comment: Nas Cantigas de Santa Maria temos _nh_, mas _ll_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No artigo de Wikipédia da [língua occitana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occitan_language#Writing_system), eles escrevem que esta ortografia entrou no idioma português pela influência de um bispo de Braga (1047 ᴀ.ᴅ.) que veio originalmente duma cidade francesa de fala occitana (em inglês, pois a versão em português não tem esse detalhe):

> The Occitan classical orthography and the Catalan orthography are quite similar: They show the very close ties of both languages. The digraphs *lh* and *nh*, used in the classical orthography, were adopted by the orthography of Portuguese, presumably by [Gerald of Braga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerald_of_Braga), a monk from [Moissac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moissac), who became bishop of Braga in Portugal in 1047, playing a major role in modernizing written Portuguese using classical Occitan norms.<sup>[55]</sup>
>
> 55. Jean-Pierre Juge (2001) *Petit précis – Chronologie occitane – Histoire & civilisation*, p. 25

Comment: Onde é que diz que Braga era uma cidade de fala occitana? O [bispo Geraldo de Braga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerald_of_Braga) veio da Gasconha, mas acho muito estranho que o occitano alguma vez tivesse sido a língua principal de Braga.

Comment: @Jacinto Não era Braga mas sim Moissac que era de fala occitana. :)

Comment: Lol, erro meu. Tinhas *duma* e eu li *uma*.

Comment: Does Catalan use *lh* and *nh* too then?

Comment: @Jacinto No, for /ɲ/ Catalan uses *ny* as in *Catalunya* [kətə'luɲə], while for /ʎ/ it uses *ll* as in *lluna* ['ʎunə] or *llamado* [ʎə'maðu]. It also has the unusual digraph *l·l* for a (sometimes) geminated /l/ as in *novel·la* [nu'vɛl.lə] and the even odder digraph *nc*  (well, or *ng* as in English) written at the end of the word to represent /ŋ/, as in *tinc* ['tĩŋ] (meaning PT *tenho*) or *blanc* ['blãŋ]. You’ll notice that the vowel reduction in unstressed syllables in Catalan is extremely similar to what happens in Portuguese, despite being wholly absent from Castilian.

Comment: O que se aprende por aqui...

Answer (score 0):

diria que os sons nh e o lh, também existentes noutras línguas românicas, nos vêm do Grego. No Grego Antigo os sons λι,li e νι,ni, soavam a lh e a nh, respetivamente. No Grego moderno, esses sons continuam bem vivos, actua is.

Comment: Carl, a tua resposta passa um bocado ao lado da pergunta. A pergunta é sobre as letras, sobre o uso de *nh* para representar o som  [ɲ] (noutras línguas é representado por *ñ* ou *gn*) e  de *lh* para representar o som  [ʎ]  (noutras línguas é representado por *ll* ou *gl*). Sobre os sons propriamente ditos já existe [esta outre pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/2927/por-que-raz%C3%A3o-s%C3%A3o-t%C3%A3o-raras-as-palavras-que-come%C3%A7am-por-lh-e-nh), com respostas interessantes. Poderás querer ver.