# Por que razão são tão raras as palavras que começam por «lh» e «nh»?

Tags: fonologia

Eu ia já todo lampeiro dizer que não havia palavras que começassem por *lh* ou *nh*, mas por descargo de consciência consultei um dicionário, e há. Poucas, mas há.

Por *lh* temos, claro está, *lhe, lho, lha* (*eu não lhe contei nada*) e ainda [*lhama*](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=lhama) (tecido de ouro, prata ou cobre prateado ou dourado; variante de *lama*, o animal), [*lhano*](http://www.aulete.com.br/lhano) (sincero, franco), [*lhaneza*](http://www.aulete.com.br/lhaneza) (franqueza), [*lhanura*](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=lhanura) (planura), [*lheguelhé*](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=lheguelh%E9) (João-ninguém), *lheísmo* (substituição no tratamento por *voçê* dos pronomes *o* e *a* por *lhe*), e o meu favorito, [*lhufas*](http://www.aulete.com.br/lhufas) (pronome indefinido, *nada, coisa nenhuma*, equivalente a [*népias*](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/n%C3%A9pias) no ptPT). E é tudo.

Começando por *nh*, o Houaiss tem uma página inteira, entre as 62,4 da letra *n*, e as 3800 do dicionário inteiro. A grande maioria são de origem ameríndia, principalmente tupi. Algumas são de origem africana. Outras têm origem no italiano ([*nhoque*](http://www.aulete.com.br/nhoque)) ou no português (como [*nhô, nhonhô*](http://www.aulete.com.br/nh%C3%B4), de senhor). Mas mesmo uma página inteira é muito pouco. Mesmo o *z* tem 15, e o *x* 9 mais 34 do *ch*.

Qual a razão desta raridade? Imagino que tenha que ver com a maneira como os sons representados por *lh* e *nh* evoluíram do latim; e que por alguma razão essa evolução não se tenha dado em início de palavra. Espero que os nossos latinistas saibam explicar isto como deve ser.

Comment: Lhama, lhaneza, lhano, lhe, lheísmo e lhufas são as únicas com lh no início, e nhoque é a única que começa com nh.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vou desenvolver um pouco a resposta de @tchrist, já que a citação que ele fez exemplifica o caso do desenvolvimento ⟨lh⟩ e não explica ⟨nh⟩. Mas em resumo, a resposta é a mesma: não há ⟨lh-, nh-⟩ em início de palavra pois os fenômenos que desenvolveram estes sons não ocorreram em início de palavra (exceto em "lhe(o/a)" e já explico o porque).

Primeiramente, em nosso vocabulário há palavras que começam com ⟨lh-⟩, mas que são vindas doutras línguas ("lhama", "Lhasa-Apso"), ou formadas no português através de neologismos, onomatopeias e reduções ("lhufas < bulhufas"). O mesmo ocorre para o dígrafo ⟨nh⟩ ("nheco", "nheengatu", "nhá < sinhá", "nhô < sinhô").

A maior parte das palavras com esses sons foram criadas por um fenômeno chamado [iotização](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iotation). Iotização é uma forma de palatização desencadeada quando uma consoante se funde com um som palatal próximo (geralmente a semivogal `/j/`). Enquanto que [palatização](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalization_(sound_change)) é uma alteração fonética de um som não-palatal que torna-se palatal (neste caso `/l > ʎ/` e `/n > ɲ/`).

### Dos fenômenos que formaram o ⟨lh⟩

No primeiro caso, /ʎ/ surgiu do /-lj-/ ou /-jl-/ intervocálico. Esse /j/ ocorria no latim vulgar em locais onde, no latim clássico, haviam /i/ ou /e/. Em notação fonética, as mudanças foram, do latim clássico ao latim vulgar e ao português:

```
LATIM > VULGAR > PORT. -- EXEMPLO
/VliV > VljV   > VʎV/  -- "melior >  melhor"
/VleV > VljV   > VʎV/  -- "valeo  > valho" (primeira pessoa do verbo "valer")
/VilV > VjlV   > VʎV/  -- "ille   > lhe"

Onde /V/ é uma vogal qualquer.
```

No proto-português as consoantes /c/ e /g/ pós-vocálica, quando ocorria antes de outra consoante, transformou-se em /j/. Por exemplo, "oito", que veio do latim "octo", além de "noite < noctem" e "leito < lectum". Esse fenômeno também aconteceu antes do /l/, por exemplo, o latim vulgar "mac'la" (vinda do latim clássico "macula") transformou-se no proto-português /majla/ que, por iotização, virou "malha". Veja a lista dessas mudanças em notação fonética:

```
LATIM  > VULGAR > PROTO > PORT.  EXEMPLO
/VkulV > VklV   > VjlV  > VʎV/   "aurecula  > *orec'la   > orelha"
/VtulV > VklV   > VjlV  > VʎV/   "vetulum   > *vec'lu    > velho"
/VgulV > VglV   > VjlV  > VʎV/   "coagulare > *coag'lare > coalhar"
```

Como pôde ver, não há como este som aparecer no início de palavra, pois:

- A primeira mudança só ocorreu com um /-lj-/ ou /-jl-/ intervocálico (entre vogais), o que só é possível no interior de uma palavra, exceto pelo pronome "lhe", que é um enclítico. Um enclítico é morfologicamente uma palavra individual, mas é fonologicamente ligada a outra. Em português os enclíticos são reconhecidos pelo uso do hífen: "dei-lhe", "dou-te".
- A segunda mudança ocorreu com /-cl-/ ou /-gl-/ intervocálico, o que só é possível no interior de uma palavra. Palavras como "clave" não transformaram-se em "lhave" pois a transformação /c > j/ só aconteceu após uma vogal, portanto as transformações no proto-português foram "noite < noctem" e "majla < macla", mas não "jlave < clave".

### Dos fenômenos que formaram o ⟨nh⟩

Dois dos três fenômenos de formação do ⟨nh⟩ são semelhantes e paralelos ao do ⟨lh⟩.

Primeiro a iotização do /-nj-/ intervocálico do latim vulgar:

```
LATIM  > VULGAR > PORT.   EXEMPLO
/VniV  > VnjV   > VɲV/    "seniorem > senhor"
/VneV  > VnjV   > VɲV/    "baneum   > banho"
```

Também há a iotização por semivogais criadas a partir de uma consoante oclusiva pós-vocálica no proto-português:

```
LATIM  > VULGAR > PORT.  EXEMPLO
/VgnV  > VjnV   > VɲV/   "tam magnum > *tammajno > tamanho"
```

E, no terceiro caso, o /ɲ/ foi criado após /i/ e antes de outra vogal, tal como especifico [aqui](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1804/como-%C3%A9-que-una-e-unus-do-latim-deram-em-uma-e-um-no-portugu%C3%AAs/4626#4626):

```
LATIM > PT ANTIGO > PORT.     EXEMPLO
/i.nõ > ĩ.o       > ĩ.ɲo/     "vinum   > vỹo   > vinho"
/i.na > ĩ.a       > ĩ.ɲa/     "gallina > galỹa > galinha"
```

Novamente, esses fenômenos não podiam ocorrer no início de palavra pois:

- O primeiro caso só ocorreu com o /-nj-/ intervocálico, o que não é possível no início de palavras.
- O segundo caso só ocorreu com o /-gn-/ intervocálico, o que não é possível no início de palavras.
- O terceiro caso só ocorreu com o /-n-/ após /i/, o que não é possível no início de palavras (pois um /n/ no início de palavra é o primeiro fonema e ocorre após nada, não tem como ele estar, ao mesmo tempo, após /i/ e após nada).

### Conclusão

As consequências do fato desses fenômenos terem sido desencadeados sempre após uma vogal e antes de outra são:

- Não há ⟨lh, nh⟩ no início de palavra; exceto "lhe" que, por ser um enclítico, faz fonologicamente parte do verbo que a antecede ("doulhe") embora que morfologicamente seja uma palavra por si só ("dou-lhe"; além de "lhe dou", no português moderno).
- ⟨lh, nh⟩ só ocorrem entre duas vogais; exceto "lhe" que, por ser um enclítico, acontece após a vogal final de um verbo conjugado.

[Este livro](https://edisciplinas.usp.br/pluginfile.php/158086/mod_resource/content/1/TEYSSIER_%20HistoriaDaLinguaPortuguesa.pdf) discute essas transformações desde o latim clássico ao latim vulgar e ao galego-português.

Comment: Excelente: eu preciso das coisas explicadas tintim por tintim. Então o /lj/ no início da palavra? Porquê? Por só ocorrer após a sílaba tónica (*Gália, parafernália*)?

Comment: Como disse, o /-lj-/ devia ser intervocálico para transformar-se em /-ʎ-/. Se ele ocorrer no início da palavra, não tem como ser intervocálico. Perceba que, no português, o ⟨lh⟩ e ⟨nh⟩ ocorre sempre entre duas vogais: "velho", "milho", "filho", "vinho", "senhor".

Comment: Sim, mas há alguma razão para só o /lj/ intervocálico se transformar em /-ʎ-/? Bem, na verdade, parece-me que pelo menos em português o /lj/ só ocorre imediatamente a seguir a vogal tónica, o que obriga a ser intervocálico, mas não tenha a certeza se isso é verdade ou se o seria no latim.

Comment: Por exemplo, pelo menos no meu sotaque, *liana* é /li'jɐnɐ/ e *aliado* é /ɐli'jadu/, ao contrário de *Gália,* /'galjɐ/.

Comment: Sim, no português moderno também me parece que /-lj-/ só ocorre imediatamente *após* vogais tônicas, não sei o motivo. Mas no latim vulgar ibérico, o /-lj-/ ocorria também imediatamente *antes* de vogais tônicas, tendo gerado o /-ʎ-/ nestas posições (ex.: "semelhante", "melhor", "olhar", "aconselhável" ...). Creio que o fenômeno que criou o /-ʎ-/ só aconteceu nas proximidades de vogais tônicas, seja antes ou depois, pois ainda não encontrei qualquer contraprova disso, exceto em flexões e derivações daquelas palavras (e.g., "olharíamos", "semelhantemente").

Answer (score 8):

A razão pela qual (quase) não há palavras nativas em português começando dessa maneira é porque as mudanças fonológicas do latim que nos dão os dígrafos *nh* e *lh* não aconteceram no início da palavra.

De [*The Romance Languages*; Harris & Vincent, Oxford University Press, 1990](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0195208293), pp. 139–140:

> […] In addition, intervocalic /l/ and /n/ were effaced, and geminate /ll nn/ reduced to single /l n/. […]
>
> A wide range of palatal and dental consonants results from the palatalising influence of front vowels and yod as shown in Table 4.4. The development of an affricate /ʧ/ from obstruent + lateral clusters is an innovation peculiar to Galician-Portuguese and Leonese, and stands in strange contrast to the absence of delateralisation in /ʎ/ < /lj/ (compare Port. *chave* (OPort. [ʧave/]), *filho* and Sp. *llave, hijo* (p. 84)). The affricate /ʧ/ later merged with the fricative /ʃ/  in southern dialects (as in French, cf. p. 212). […]
>
> ### Palatalisations
>
> ```
>  ʎ  <  -lj-             filho           < FĬLIUM
>        -Cl-             velho           < VĔT(Ŭ)LUM
>                         olho            < ŎC(Ŭ)LUM
>
>  ɲ  <  -nj-             vinha           < VĪNEAM
>        -jn- < -gn-      lenha           < LIGNAM
>        epenthetic ȷ̃       vinho < vĩo     < VĪNUM 
>
> […]
>
> ʃ < ʧ < Cl-     OPort.  chantar         < PLĀNTARE
>                         chave           < CLAVEM
>                         chuva < chuiva  < PLŬVIAM
> […]
> ```

Mas não tenho nenhuma explicação para *lhe / lhes*, que parecem ser palavras únicas.

Comment: Compreendo  a palatização em *filho* e *vinha* por influência do *yod*. Mas não a palatização em *velho, olho, lenha*. Qual foi a vogal frontal nestes casos? -Cl- refere-se a *oculum*? E portanto estes *liu-* e *nea-* não ocorrem no início de palavra em latim?

Comment: @Jacinto parece que `Cl` significa "consoante + /l/", então refere às duas, *vetulum* e *oculum*.

Answer (score 6):

O pronome *lhe* é derivado do pronome *illi* (dativo de *ille*) do latim (e *lhe* + *o* > *lho*, *lhe* + *a* > *lha*, etc.).

Não sei se é um caso de metátese *i* ↔ *l* (illi > /ili/ > /lii/ > /lie/ > /lje/ = lhe) ou se a palatização foi uma consequência da elisão do primeiro *i*, mas em *lhe*, *lho*, etc., o som /lj/ no começo da palavra é um caso raro (e também vem do latim).

Muitas outras palavras começando em *lh-* vêm do *ll-* ([ʎ]) do espanhol: *lhama*, *lhaneza*, *lhano*, *lhanos*, *lhanura*.

(Etimologias do Aurélio.)

Comment: Sempre às ordens. Tens aí todas as palavras em *lh-* (do Houaiss) menos o *lheguelhé* e o *lhufas*.

Comment: O Aurélio não tem etimologias para *lheguelhé* e *lhufas*...

Comment: Houaiss: *lheguelhé* < *lagalhé* , origem obscura; diz-se resultar da soletração *lê + agá + é = lhé* (*l + h+ e = lhé*), João Ribeiro (*Frases feitas*) relaciona com *leguleio* na aceção pejorativa «o rábula que conhece apenas de memória o texto das leis e não tem carta para advogar»;  *lhufas* < *bulhufas*, vocativo onomatopeico [mas de quê?!]