# Por que razão o fonema /ɾ/ ( r de caro) não aparece nunca em início de palavra?

Tags: fonologia

Se os sons /ʎ/ (gra*lh*a) e /ɲ/ (ma*nh*ã) são raros em início de palavra [(ver esta pergunta)](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/2927/por-que-raz%C3%A3o-s%C3%A3o-t%C3%A3o-raras-as-palavras-que-come%C3%A7am-por-lh-e-nh), o /ɾ/ (ca*r*o) é inexistente. Como é que os dois sons /ʁ/ (ca*rr*o) e /ɾ/ surgiram no português? Já existiam dois erres diferentes no latim? E por que razão o /ɾ/ não aparece nunca em início de palavra?

Comment: Question about rolled Rs on Latin.SE: [Why is 'r' often rolled in modern classical Latin?](http://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/107/why-is-r-often-rolled-in-modern-classical-latin)

Comment: (This is not an answer.) That's because the two rhotic phonemes contrast only between oral vowels; otherwise they occur in complementary distribution.  It's been suggested that these may therefore represent a single rhotic archiphoneme /R/, being neutralized into the same allophone in the initial position at the very least and sometimes (often?) for other non-intervocalic positions as well. The contrasting intervocalic rhotic, the only one in initial position, may have originated from a geminated /ɾɾ/ > /r/, then much later /r/ > /ʁ/ in many speakers.

Comment: @tchrist «the two rhotic phonemes contrast only between oral vowels». Is that about Latin? Not sure that's true in some European Portuguese dialects. Say, in Alentejo, *vou ali ver um /tʁenu/* is different from  *vou ali ver um /tɾenu/*.

Comment: @Jacinto Do those mean different things, even if said differently? [WIkipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonologia_da_l%C3%ADngua_portuguesa) says “Os dois fonemas róticos, /ʁ/ e /ɾ/, sofrem contraste apenas quando entre vogais. No início das palavras e depois de /l/, /z/, /ʒ/ e de vogais nasais apenas a primeira ocorre e nos conjuntos consonantais (ex: pr, fr, cr,...) apenas o segundo acontece, enquanto em outras situações a maioria dos dialetos usa apenas a segunda. No entanto, diversos dialetos brasileiros, entre eles o dialeto carioca, utilizam-se da segunda no final das sílabas.”

Comment: @tchrist In European Portuguese many unstressed ***e*** is hardly audible or completely elided in relaxed speech. Hence *terreno* (piece of land in the example) will basically sound /tʁenu/. Many people in southern Portugal will pronounce ***ei*** as /e/; hence *treino*  will be pronounced /tɾenu/. Similarly, for many people in all of Portugal, relaxed pronnunciation of *Ferreira* (common surname) will be /fʁɐjɾɐ/ and *freira* is pronnounced /fɾɐjɾɐ/.

Comment: No início da palavra /ɾ/ tem som de /ʁ/

Comment: @GabrielAnderson Imagino que queiras dizer que a letra ***r*** em início de palavra tem o som /ʁ/. Mas não é por isso que o som /ɾ/ não aparece em início de palavra. Se aparecesse, poderíamos usar erre duplo em início de palavra para o som /ʁ/ (e.g. *rrainha*, como se vê nalguns textos medievais) e o um erre único para o som /ɾ/.

Comment: @Jacinto _Imagino que queiras dizer que a letra r em início de palavra tem o som /ʁ/._ Exatamente!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Havia, sim, mais tardiamente, no latim dois sons róticos distisintos. O /ɾ/ (tepe alveolar sonoro), como o atual e o som /r/ (vibrante alveolar sonora), orindo de "Rs" geminados e no início de palavras. Um sistema como o do castelhano e do italiano atuais.

No português, por volta do século XIX, um processo parecido com o que ocorreu no francês, fez com que a vibrante fosse à parte de trás da boca, tornando-a o "som de dois erres".

Basicamente, o fato de no latim não ocorrer o tepe no início de palavras, fez com que o português também não o tivesse!

## ENGLISH VERSION

There was, indeed, lately, in latin two distinct rhotic sounds. The /ɾ/ (voiced alveolar tap), like the modern one and the sound /r/ (voiced alveolar thrill), originated from the geminate "Rs" and those at the beginning of words. A system that resembles the Castillian one and the Italian one.

In Portuguese, around the 19th century, a process, that looks like the one that happened in French, made the thrill go to a posterior part of the mouth, making it the "two Rs sound".

Basically, the fact that latin didn't have a tap at the beginning of words makes the portuguese language lack them!

Comment: Excelente. Então, se houve dois erres no latim só tardiamente, qual foi o original? O vibrante, que mais tarde, quando precedido de vogal, se aligeirou para tepe? Tou a especular; é só o que me parece mais plausível.

Comment: Há muuuito tempo pode ter sido só o "r" como tepe que se modificou nos ambientes de início de palavra e quando gemeniado!

Comment: Bem visto que também há o geminado. Esse duplo tepe seria análogo ao duplo tt, ll, etc., que os italianos distinguem de t, l único?

Comment: Exatamente! Duas consoantes repetidas uma seguida da outra

Answer (score 1):

No Brasil tem uma cantora chamada "Baby Consuelo" que deu para suas filhas nomes diferentes. A uma das filhas ela deu um nome que usa o fonema **/ɾ/ (caro)** (Saiba mais sobre isso [aqui](http://babydobrasil.webnode.com.br/products/voc%C3%AA%20sabe%20o%20significado%20dos%20nomes%20dos%20filhos%20de%20baby-/) e [aqui](https://tuliovillaca.wordpress.com/2013/10/30/palavra-nova-que-dispensa-explicacao/).)

Uma das filhas recebeu o nome de Riroca (todos os `r` com **/ɾ/ (caro)**). Como não existia maneira de escrever esse fonema no início de uma palavra, a grafia foi registrada como **'Riroca**.

Mais tarde ela mesma mudou o nome e a única palavra iniciada com este fonema sumiu. (Embora a palavra fosse um nome próprio, e por isso não estivesse registada em dicionário nenhum.)

## English version

The Brazilian singer "Baby Consuelo" gave her daughters particular names. She gave one of the daughters a name that uses the phoneme ** / ɾ / (caro) ** (You can read more about it [here](http://babydobrasil.webnode.com.br/products/voc%C3%AA%20sabe%20o%20significado%20dos%20nomes%20dos%20filhos%20de%20baby-/) and [here](https://tuliovillaca.wordpress.com/2013/10/30/palavra-nova-que-dispensa-explicacao/).)

One of the daughters was named Riroca (all `r`s being ** / ɾ / (caro) **). As there was no way to spell that phoneme at the start of a word, her name was written as ** 'Riroca **.

Later the daughter herself changed the name, and this word starting with this phoneme disappeared. (Although it was a name, and thus not registered in dictionaries.)